# three.js remove specific object from scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an array of Meshes, each Mesh has stored in a name property its ID. I would like to ask you, if it is possible to remove from scene an object with specific ID. Something like this.

```
var geo = some geometry;
var mat = some material;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var object = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
  object.name = i;  // i would serve as ID in this case
}
```

After this, I would like to delete/remove some of these objects...
Maybe some function like

```
 remove(id);
```

....

```
 var remove = function (id) {
  ... some magic
  scene.remove(...) // and this would remove that object, with id passed as parameter 
 }
```

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes it is:

```
function remove(id) {
  scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(id));
}
```

see: [Object3D.remove()](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L329-L353) and [Object3D.getObjectByName()](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L361-L365)

Comment: These line-specific links become outdated as the master branch gets updates, consider using a [permanent link](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/) instead. Current: [`.remove()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a1daef37e5a6b80d0173af54edd000202b95fca5/src/core/Object3D.js#L383-L411), [`.getObjectByName()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a1daef37e5a6b80d0173af54edd000202b95fca5/src/core/Object3D.js#L419-L423)